# when I print out the value of variable it is correct otherwise it does not change. C language

Tags: python, c

I defined a variable `m_index` with initial value -1. I increase this variable in the first for loop and then use the increased value in second for loop.

The problem is when I put the print command at the end of first loop, the value of `m_index` is correct but when I comment the print command, the value of `m_index` remains -1.

I would appreciate any help. The code is written in C language using python API and my platform is linux ubuntu 64bit.

```
static PyObject *get_outside_members(PyArrayObject *AA, PyArrayObject *bb, npy_int AA_index)
{
    npy_intp m_index=-1, fp_index=-1, o_index=0, i=0;  
    npy_double distance=0.0, max_distance=0;
    PyArrayObject *tmembers, *tfurthest_points;
    npy_intp dims[1];
    PyObject *r;
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    dims[0]=outs_N;
    tmembers=(PyArrayObject *)PyArray_SimpleNew(1,dims,NPY_INT);
    if(tmembers==NULL)
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,"Could not create tmembers array");
        return NULL;
    }
    distances=(PyArrayObject *)PyArray_SimpleNew(1,dims,NPY_DOUBLE);
    if(distances==NULL)
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,"Could not create distances array");
        return NULL;
    }
    tfurthest_points=(PyArrayObject *)PyArray_SimpleNew(1,dims,NPY_INT);
    if(tfurthest_points==NULL)
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,"Could not create tfurthest_points array");
        return NULL;
    }
    dims[0]=1;
    furthest_dist=(PyArrayObject *)PyArray_SimpleNew(1,dims,NPY_DOUBLE);
    if(furthest_dist==NULL)
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,"Could not create furthest_dist array");
        return NULL;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------  
    for(i=0;i<outs_N;i++)
    {
        o_index=outsides(i);    
        distance = distpalne(AA,bb,AA_index,o_index);
        if(i == 0)
            max_distance = distance;
        else if(distance > max_distance)
           max_distance = distance;
        if(distance >= 0)
        {
            m_index++;                
            tmembers(m_index)=o_index;
            distances(m_index)=distance;       
        }
    }
    //printf("m_index=%d\n",m_index);  
    for(i=0;i<=m_index;i++)
    {
        if(distances(i) == max_distance)
        {
            fp_index++;      
            tfurthest_points(fp_index)=tmembers(i);      
        }
    }
    PyArray_Return(tmembers);
}
```

Comment: seems `printf` nothing do with it.

Answer (score -1):

I am very sure this does not have anything to do with the `printf`. `printf` get's the variables value by value and therefore cannot change anything. If I were you, I would check that again after some time has passed.

In addition, when you are debugging using `print` statements, always add `fflush(stdout);` after every `print` statement to make sure that the value is immediately printed. As an alternative, you could print to `stderr` which is flushed automatically:

```
fprintf(stderr, "prints directly");
```

Another thing I would check is, that you do not have any memory-errors. You can use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for that.